# Counting login attempts flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Im trying to get a flash notification for each failed attempt to login with number of failed attempts

My imports:

```
from time import strftime
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, session, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, LoginManager, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
import datetime
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, ValidationError, AnyOf, Regexp, NoneOf
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
# pip instal flask flask_sqlalchemy flask_login flask_bcrypt flask_wtf wtforms email_validator
# terminal cmds python, from main import db, db.create_all(), exit()
# pip install password-strength
```

My main file:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
# picFolder = os.path.join('static', 'fantasy')
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretcodeneeded'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.app_context().push()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login"

with open('CommonPassword.txt', 'r') as file:
    passes = file.read().splitlines()

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    count = 0

def reset(self):
    self.count = 0

def counting(self):
    self.count += 1

def tots(self):
    return self.count
class registeror(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(
        min=4, max=20)], render_kw={'placeholder': 'Username'})
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(
        min=12, max=20), NoneOf(passes, message='Password is to simple try again'), Regexp("^(?=.*[a-z])", flags=0,
                                                                                           message='Password must have a lowercase character'),
                                         Regexp("^(?=.*[A-Z])", flags=0,
                                                message='Password must have an uppercase character'),
                                         Regexp("^(?=.*\\d)", flags=0, message='Password must contain a number'),
                                         Regexp("(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])", flags=0,
                                                message='Password must contain a special character')],
                             render_kw={'placeholder': 'Password'}, )
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        existing = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if existing:
            raise ValidationError(
                "That username already exists. Please choose a different one.")

class loginor(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(
        min=4, max=20)], render_kw={'placeholder': 'Username'})
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(
        min=12, max=20)], render_kw={'placeholder': 'Password'})
    submit = SubmitField('Login')


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("main.html")


@app.route("/login/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = loginor()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        counting(user)
        if user:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                # login_user(user)
                reset(user)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            atempt = tots(user)
            flash('Invalid login, this is attempt '+atempt)
    return render_template("login.html", form=form)


@app.route('/dashboard/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    datetime.datetime.now()
    value = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return render_template('dashboard.html', content=value)


@app.route('/logout/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/rpg/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def rpg():
    # pic1 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'fantasy.jpg')
    return render_template("rpg.html")


@app.route('/ttc/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def ttc():
    headers = ['game', 'company', 'scale', 'cost of entry']
    tableData = [
        {'game': 'Warhammer 40k', 'company': 'Games Workshop', 'scale': 'platoon-battalion', 'cost of entry': '$540+'},
        {'game': 'Age of Sigmar', 'company': 'Games Workshop', 'scale': 'platoon-battalion', 'cost of entry': '$540+'},
        {'game': 'Bolt Action', 'company': 'Warlord Games', 'scale': 'platoon', 'cost of entry': '$75+'},
        {'game': 'Kings of War', 'company': 'Mantic', 'scale': 'battalion-Corps', 'cost of entry': '$250'},
    ]
    return render_template("ttcombat.html", headers=headers, tableData=tableData)


@app.route("/register/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = registeror()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data)
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template("register.html", form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My html works fine but it will either show nothing or it will attempt to log in ten times then not do anything.

I was expecting it to give my a failed attempts after submit button is clicked.

Any help would be great.